# How can I make an ORDER BY Ladder properly?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have this Query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM table 
ORDER BY
        column = 'A B C D E F G' DESC,
        column = 'A B C D E F' DESC,
        column = 'A B C D E' DESC,
        column = 'A B C D' DESC,
        column = 'A B C' DESC,
        column = 'A B' DESC,
        column = 'A' DESC
GROUP BY id
```

I used the ladder method in the `ORDER BY` And I may have multiple stacked ladders like this:

```
A B C D E F G H I K L M 
A B C D E F G H I K L
A B C D E F G H I K
A B C D E F G H I
A B C D E F G H
A B C D E F G
A B C D E F
A B C D E
A B C D
A B C
A B
A
N O P Q R S T V X Y Z
N O P Q R S T V X Y
N O P Q R S T V X
N O P Q R S T V
N O P Q R S T
N O P Q R S
N O P Q R
N O P Q
N O P
N O
N
```

Is there a better way to do this `ORDER BY` instead of making a line for each step of the ladder? I can make a `PHP function` to deal with this Job, But is this even good for the `MySQL`?

or How would you deal with such a Query exactly? I'm concerned about `Performance`.

To get the following Result in SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f4c815/4/1

Comment: you can order by the first letter, then by the length of the data in descending order

Comment: @Kobi is that what Gordon answer meant? That what I understood after looking about `substring_index` and `length`

Comment: yes, his answers does the job.

Comment: Perhaps a dup of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204323/splitting-a-string-and-order-by-desc-its-matching-values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
order by substring_index(col, ' ', 1),
         length(col) desc
```

Comment: Can you explain to me how does it work exactly? I understood you selected the first part of the string with `substring_index` which is the letter `A` and ordered it by `ASC`, Then you ordered by the length of `col DESC`, But that would act like `7 DESC`, I don't get how it works exactly, Would this work if there is other `columns` to order?

Comment: `length(col)` will provide the length of the data in the col column `for each rows`,  In your case : 8, 12 , 9 ,8 etc...  then the order by clause will sort in descending order: 12, 11 , 10 , 9 ..

Comment: @Kobi Can't the string be defined in this case?